# How to make infinite animation with Angular6?

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

I maked a 3d truck using html and css.  If an any variable (**x**) is true, truck tires is rotate 360 degree. If x=false, truck tires stop the rotation. I make this with css for only infinite rotate.

```
.whell{
   animation: round 2s infinite linear ;
}

 @keyframes round {
   from {
     transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   to {
     transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
   }
```

This css codes is working but not stopped tires depending on the variable. I decided to make with Angular Animations;

```
animations: [

    trigger('x',[
      state('true', style({
        transform: 'rotate(360deg)'

      })),

      transition('* => *', animate('2s'))

    ])
  ]
```

Truck's tires is rotating but only 2 second.. Is there a way to rotate it infinite in Angular6? I want **infinite**, not 2 second. I would appreciate if you help. Thank you...

Comment: How did you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about using it like this:

[ngClass]="x?'whell':'classWithNoAnimation'"

if x is true then switch to hell otherwise switch to classWithNoAnimation

Comment: Thanks your answer. I know it's used this way but I don't want to write more css code